# Bypassing Triggers after workflow

Tags: trigger

I thought I had solved the problem of my triggers re-running after my workflows.

I have a trigger handler which uses a variable to determine if the trigger ran already.  I tested this with bulk updates and it worked fine.  I used the data loader to upload 245 new opportunities and it ran two batches while updating the names properly.

Now I'm testing and when I insert two individual opportunities in the test class, the trigger only fires once.  Is this something with the test class or am I off base on my logic?  Here is the code:

First, here is the code on the trigger handler:

```
if(Trigger.isBefore){
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
      if(clsUtility.firstRunBeforeInsert){
        handler.onBeforeInsert(trigger.new);
        clsUtility.firstRunBeforeInsert=false;
      }
    }
    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
      if(clsUtility.firstRunBeforeUpdate){
        handler.onBeforeUpdate(trigger.new, trigger.oldmap);
        clsUtility.firstRunBeforeUpdate=false;
      }
    }
    //if(Trigger.isDelete){}
}
```

And here is the test class where I create two opportunities. (the first opportunity runs the code but not the second

```
 Opportunity Opp1 = new Opportunity(
        AccountId=customer.Id,
        Type ='Health New Business',
        Ownerid = u.id,
        Incumbent_Carrier__c = acctcarrier.id,
        broker__c = broker1.id,
        Total_Eligible_Employees__c=1,
        Total_Employees_Enrolling__C=1,
        Name='Opp1',
        Stagename='Sales Proposal Prep',
        CloseDate=  Date.newInstance(system.today().year(),06,1),
        region__C='NJ - Health',
        market_segment__C='Midsize',
        Date_Received_Quote_Request__c = Date.newInstance(system.today().year(),06,1),
        Annual_Revenue__c = 10000,
        RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('New Business Health').RecordTypeId);
    insert Opp1;

    Opportunity Opp2 = new Opportunity(
        AccountId=customer.Id,
        Type ='Health New Business',
        Ownerid = u.id,
        Incumbent_Carrier__c = acctcarrier.id,
        broker__c = broker1.id,
        Total_Eligible_Employees__c=1,
        Total_Employees_Enrolling__C=1,
        Name='Opp2',
        Stagename='Sales Proposal Prep',
        CloseDate=  Date.newInstance(system.today().year(),07,1),
        region__C='NJ - Health',
        market_segment__C='Midsize',
        Date_Received_Quote_Request__c = Date.newInstance(system.today().year(),06,1),
        Annual_Revenue__c = 10000,
        RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('New Business Health').RecordTypeId);
    insert Opp2;
```

Thank you!!

Fred

Answer (score 0):

Static variables only reset at the beginning of a transaction. In Apex, all DML in a method (e.g a unit test) is a single transaction. For this reason, one should usually use a Set and store the individual Id values. However, this mayalso cause problems withpartial retries. You should instead consider wiring your triggers such that they only fire when changes occur.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  When you say that I should, "consider wiring your triggers such that they only fire when changes occur"  you mean to not make any changes in the trigger unless data changes that requires it, is that correct?  When my workflow updates a field, I can't stop the before and after triggers from actually firing, isn't that correct?  I just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: Also, I am confused why I did not have an issue processing 240 records when I updated data in the sanbdbox, but I am having the issue with inserting the test data.  When I processed the 240 records via the data loader, 200 were put in one batch which was one execution (triggers ran) and the other 40 were a different batch (different execution) and the triggers ran.  So I did not see any issues there.  It was just the test data that did not fire the trigger twice on two inserts.  I really appreciate your time!   Fred

Comment: @Fred (a) Yes, I prefer the use of "rising edge" triggers. They will still run, but won't perform duplicate DML operations (in general). Using a single Boolean is almost always a Bad Idea. (b) In API calls, every 200 records are processed as a single transaction. In Apex Code, up to 10,000 records can be processed in a single transaction. You'll want to see other questions on this site about "recursion blockers."

Comment: Thank you very much!!